# How to convert fractional seconds to milliseconds?

Tags: python, math, time

```
import time
l=[]
start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(20000000):
    l.append(i)
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end-start)
```

Yields **2.7262994**

I'm not sure how to read that. If 2 is seconds, then how is there 7262994 milliseconds? Does anyone know how to convert fractional seconds to milliseconds?

Comment: That's a time in seconds. There are 2 s and 726.2994 ms; or 2 s, 726 ms, and 299.4 μs; or ...

Comment: 7262994 is not miliseconds:
7 is seconds/10
2 is seconds/100 
6 is seconds/1000. (miliseconds)
.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 1000 milliseconds in one second, so just multiply the number of seconds by 1000:

```py
>>> seconds = 2.7262994
>>> milliseconds = seconds * 1000
>>> milliseconds
2726.2994
```

If you want a whole number of milliseconds, then round it and convert to an int:

```py
>>> int(round(milliseconds))
2726
```

Comment: That's not fractional seconds

Comment: @melMass Not sure what your objection is - I simply used the number provided by the OP.

Comment: Timestamp values have precision in fractional seconds that range from 0 to 9. For example, a precision of 0 means that no fractional seconds are stored, 3 means that the timestamp stores milliseconds and 9 means a precision of nanoseconds. 0 is the minimum precision, and 9 is the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) `time.perf_counter()` returns fractional seconds. Based on that we have following case:

```
import time

start = time.perf_counter()
time.sleep(1) # sleeping 1 second
end = time.perf_counter()

print(f"Elapsed time in seconds: {end-start}")
time_elapsed_ms = (end-start)*1000
print(f"Elapsed time in miliseconds: {time_elapsed_ms}")
```

Output is:

> Elapsed time in seconds: 1.0009973929991247
>
> Elapsed time in miliseconds: 1000.9973929991247

So `1 s = 1000 ms`

**If you want your result in integer form** you can round it and then cast to int `int(round((end-start)*1000))`:

```
import time

start = time.perf_counter()
time.sleep(0.34) # sleeping 340 mili seconds
end = time.perf_counter()

print(f"Elapsed time in seconds: {end-start}")
time_elapsed_ms = int(round((end-start)*1000))
print(f"Elapsed time in miliseconds: {time_elapsed_ms}")
```

> Elapsed time in seconds: 0.3404383749948465
>
> Elapsed time in miliseconds: 340

Comment: Why multiply by 100 when 1 second is 1000 ms?

Comment: Elapsed time is 340 ms,  otherwise it would be 0.034

Answer (score 0):

.perf_counter() returns a float value (seconds) so if you cast it to int * 1000 you would have your milliseconds.